# CUDA: Accessing global memory with multiple threads

Tags: arrays, cuda, global-variables

I have a problem with the following kernel (I compiled this with compute_30,sm_30):

```
__global__ void kernel(){
// globalThreadID:
int tidX = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

bool* array;
if (tidX == 1) array = new bool[10]; // allocate global array for every thread?!

if (tidX < 10)
{
    array[tidX] = calculate something;
}


read the array.....

}
```

here the CUDA debugger sometimes complains about 9 access violations and I get only zeros when accessing the array!!

Does anybody has an idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `array` is a *thread scope* aloocation in the runtime heap. You are only allocating it for the thread with `tidX = 1`. Threads with `tidX = {0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` are attempting to dereference an uninitialised pointer. Obviously that will lead to an access voilation at runtime.

EDIT:

If you want the array to be visible and accessible to every thread *in the same block*, you can use the `__shared__` memory space. If you want the array to be visible to every thread in the kernel launch, you must either pass it as an argument to the kernel, or declare it as `__device__` memory at translation unit scope.

Comment: OK I see the problem.... But how can I make this array accessible for every thread (without declaring it number of threads-times?)

Comment: @user3694255: if this answered your question, please accept this so that it is removed from the unanswered question queue and will be more visible in search results for the next person that comes along with the same question.

Comment: You could make it a `__shared__` variable instead. [Documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared). [Examples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#axzz33It5ryyu).